# Squid: caching *.swf with variables

Tags: 12.04, server, proxy, squid

I'd recently upgraded my Ubuntu 11.10 x64 server to 12.04. In this process Squid was updated from 2.7 to 3.1. Squid 3.1 has many different options witch broke my setup. So I completely removed squid 2.7 and 3.1 and started from scratch. Everything is now working as before except for 1 thing: caching of .swf files with ?/variables. Squid 3 sees a ? as dynamic content and does not cache it.

For example, Squid 2.7 was caching the .swf file at http://ninjakiwi.com/Games/Tower-Defense/Play/Bloons-Tower-Defense-5.html and 3.1 is not.

```
<object id="mov" name="movn" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="800" height="620">
  <param name="movie" value="http://www.ninjakiwifiles.com/Games/gameswfs/btd5.swf?v=160512-2">
  <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always">
  <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000">
  <param name="flashvars" value="file=http://www.ninjakiwifiles.com/Games/gameswfs/btd5-dat.swf?v=280512">
    <p>Get Flash play Ninja Kiwi games.</p>
</object>
```

It is because of the "?v=160512-2" and "?v=280512" part. This line should be responsible for that:

```
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0    0%      0
```

But disabling it still doesn't cache the .swf files.

How do I configure Squid 3.1 to cache those files?

My current config is:

```
acl manager proto cache_object
acl localhost src 127.0.0.1/32 ::1
acl to_localhost dst 127.0.0.0/8 0.0.0.0/32 ::1
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80 # http
acl Safe_ports port 21 # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 # https
acl Safe_ports port 70 # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210 # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280 # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488 # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591 # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777 # multiling http
acl CONNECT method CONNECT
acl localnet src 192.168.2.0-192.168.2.254
acl localnet src 192.168.3.0-192.168.3.254
http_access allow manager localhost
http_access deny manager
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost
http_access allow localnet
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
cache_dir ufs /var/spool/squid 10240 16 256 
maximum_object_size 100 MB
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid3
refresh_pattern ^ftp: 1440 20% 10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher: 1440 0% 1440
refresh_pattern -i \.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico)$ 10080 90% 43200 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private
refresh_pattern -i \.(iso|avi|wav|mp3|mp4|mpeg|swf|flv|x-flv)$ 43200 90% 432000 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private
refresh_pattern -i \.(deb|rpm|exe|zip|tar|tgz|ram|rar|bin|ppt|doc|tiff)$ 10080 90% 43200 override-expire ignore-no-cache ignore-no-store ignore-private
refresh_pattern -i \.index.(html|htm)$ 0 40% 10080
refresh_pattern -i \.(html|htm|css|js)$ 1440 40% 40320
refresh_pattern Packages\.bz2$ 0       20%     4320 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern Sources\.bz2$  0       20%     4320 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern Release\.gpg$  0       20%     4320 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern Release$       0       20%     4320 refresh-ims
refresh_pattern . 0 40% 40320
cache_effective_user proxy
cache_effective_group proxy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Squid 3.1 doesn't have the storeurl_rewrite_program parameters, required to cache query parameters. There is no way to do that.